Postfix: how exactly does virtual alias recursion work?
virtual(5) is pretty unhelpful here. It just says "Virtual aliasing is recursive; to terminate recursion  for  a  specific address, alias that address to itself." narkive does appear to have some relevant answers, but the site is down (and has been for a long time?). The postfix mailing list itself has a pretty second-rate search.
Let's say example.com has a virtual alias file as follows:
john john@example.com, js@gmail.com
jane jsmith@example.com

john@example.com and jsmith@example.com are local Dovecot mailboxes in this case, so aren't actually 'addresses'. js@gmail.com is an offsite address.
Do I have to add anything to this file to stop recursion?
